# dynamic sorting in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, sorting, pagination

```
Sort sort = Sort.by(sortOrder.equals("asc") ? Sort.Direction.ASC : Sort.Direction.DESC, sortBy);
```

I m trying to sort the elements in database by this approach but when I m trying to sort by columns containing string values I m getting records   containing capital case strings values  first(i.e=A-Z) and after that small(a-z) but I want result in order
then I added IgnoreCase to method body...

```
(sort = Sort.by(new Sort.Order(sortOrder.equals("asc") ? Sort.Direction.ASC : Sort.Direction.DESC, sortBy)
                    .ignoreCase());)
```

but with this Im getting records containing string values and not getting records for columns containing integer values......give me a better solution for this??

```
    Sort sort;
        if (sortBy.equals("reviewId") || sortBy.equals("daysFromLastReview") || sortBy.equals("rating")
                || sortBy.equals("reviewDate")) {
            sort = Sort.by(sortOrder.equals("asc") ? Sort.Direction.ASC : Sort.Direction.DESC, sortBy);
        }

        else {

            sort = Sort.by(new Sort.Order(sortOrder.equals("asc") ? Sort.Direction.ASC : Sort.Direction.DESC, sortBy)
                    .ignoreCase());

        }
```

I tried this but this approach is not correct as we cannot add columns manually in application